# How do I recover ECDSA public key correctly from hashed message and signature in R || S || V format?

Tags: go, cryptography, ethereum, ecdsa, go-ethereum

I have used the following code to generate an ecdsa key-pair(`privKey` and `pubKey`), encode them and then decode them back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315404/1901320.

Next I create a hash for a message (`txnData.Payload()` is of type `[]byte`) using `crypto.Keccak256()` and sign it using `crypto.Sign()` from Ethereum's crypto package (`github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto`). This creates a 65 bit ECDSA signature in R || S || V format.

```
    hashData := crypto.Keccak256(txnData.Payload)
    sig, _ := crypto.Sign(hashData, privKey)

    pkey, _ := crypto.Ecrecover(hashData, sig) // This and pubKey do not match
```

When I try to get back the public key from the `hashData` and the ECDSA signature using `crypto.Ecrecover()` and compare it with the public key `pubKey` corresponding to the `privKey` used to  create the signature, I find that the public keys do not match. This doesn't seem like something that should happen. Any idea as to where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: This could be a good question *if* more code and input / output is provided (preferably in hex).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete working example of how to generate and verify signatures using go-ethereum.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("fad9c8855b740a0b7ed4c221dbad0f33a83a49cad6b3fe8d5817ac83d38b6a19")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.PublicKey

    publicKeyBytes := crypto.FromECDSAPub(&publicKey)

    data := []byte("hello")
    hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(data)
    fmt.Println(hash.Hex()) // 0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8

    signature, err := crypto.Sign(hash.Bytes(), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(signature)) // 0x789a80053e4927d0a898db8e065e948f5cf086e32f9ccaa54c1908e22ac430c62621578113ddbb62d509bf6049b8fb544ab06d36f916685a2eb8e57ffadde02301

    sigPublicKey, err := crypto.Ecrecover(hash.Bytes(), signature)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    matches := bytes.Equal(sigPublicKey, publicKeyBytes)
    fmt.Println(matches) // true

    sigPublicKeyECDSA, err := crypto.SigToPub(hash.Bytes(), signature)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    sigPublicKeyBytes := crypto.FromECDSAPub(sigPublicKeyECDSA)
    matches = bytes.Equal(sigPublicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes)
    fmt.Println(matches) // true

    signatureNoRecoverID := signature[:len(signature)-1] // remove recovery id
    verified := crypto.VerifySignature(publicKeyBytes, hash.Bytes(), signatureNoRecoverID)
    fmt.Println(verified) // true
}
```

Check out the [Ethereum Development with Go](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book) guide book for more examples on using go-ethereum.