# I cannot generate the ECDSA public key from her private key sequentially

Tags: go

I cannot generate the public keys in sequence.

output :./keysgo.go:33:33: cannot use PrivateKey (type []byte) as type string in argument to Public

Thank you so much for your help

important to keep this part:

```
func Public(PrivateKey string) (publicKey string) {
    var e ecdsa.PrivateKey
    e.D, _ = new(big.Int).SetString(PrivateKey, 16)
    e.PublicKey.Curve = secp256k1.S256()
    e.PublicKey.X, e.PublicKey.Y = e.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarBaseMult(e.D.Bytes())
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", elliptic.MarshalCompressed(secp256k1.S256(), e.X, e.Y))
```

i tried this

```
package main 

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1"
   
    
    
)
func Public(PrivateKey string) (publicKey string) {
    var e ecdsa.PrivateKey
    e.D, _ = new(big.Int).SetString(PrivateKey, 16)
    e.PublicKey.Curve = secp256k1.S256()
    e.PublicKey.X, e.PublicKey.Y = e.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarBaseMult(e.D.Bytes())
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", elliptic.MarshalCompressed(secp256k1.S256(), e.X, e.Y))

}

func main() {
        count, one := big.NewInt(1), big.NewInt(1)
    count.SetString("9404625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636674",10)
        PrivateKey := make([]byte, 32)
   for {
        count.Add(count, one)
        copy(PrivateKey[32-len(count.Bytes()):], count.Bytes())
        
        fmt.Printf("%x\n",Public(PrivateKey))
        

    }   
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You define `PrivateKey` as a byte slice:

```
PrivateKey := make([]byte, 32)
```

The function `Public` is defined to take a string as its arguments:

```
func Public(PrivateKey string) (publicKey string) {...}
```

Thus `Public(PrivateKey)` cannot work, because `privateKey` is the wrong type.

I am not quite sure what the code is attempting to do, but maybe `Public(string(PrivateKey))` is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your kind reply

I tried
`Public(string(PrivateKey))`

the program's response

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x4b47f9]

goroutine 1 [running]:
math/big.(*Int).Bytes(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/math/big/int.go:453

main.Public({0xc00001e1a0, 0x20})
        /root/Desktop/tuttogoprova/adressgoprova.go:17 +0x99
main.main()
        /root/Desktop/tuttogoprova/adressgoprova.go:37 +0xd3
exit status 2
```

Comment: There is a problem with your private key. It can’t be converted to big.Int. 

https://go.dev/play/p/7DLyErFqXzh

https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.SetString

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Wesley for your kind reply.
Please can you give me some solution for this problem

Infinite Thanks

Comment: I’ll try to look into it some more. Can you provide some code on how you are generating the private key?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [jochen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787051/3022460), you need to convert the `PrivateKey` byte slice to a string before sending it to the `Public` function.

Once that is done, [pointer dereference error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787440/3022460) is happening because the string you built for the private is not a valid `bigint`.

I solved the dereference issue by copying `count.String()` into the `PrivateKey` instead of `count.Bytes()`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315404/3022460) for a better way to store key pairs.

Here is some [working code](https://go.dev/play/p/x8XQVoSjcQN) that demonstrates all this. It does require `cgo` since the original code uses it, so it doesn't run in the playground.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Wesley what i am looking for is something like this https://go.dev/play/p/ws2c_bIc4M5 but i can't generate keys (private e pubbliche) sequentially THANK YOU FOR YOUR KIND

Comment: I’m unclear about what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to manipulate a private key to deterministically create new ones?

Comment: I am trying to generate public keys from private keys sequentially not random

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47499/sequential-public-key-generation-with-secret-private-keys

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Wesley not what I need but thank you for your availability

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Mr. Wesley what i am looking for is something like this  `https://go.dev/play/p/ws2c_bIc4M5`  but i can't generate keys (private e pubbliche) sequentially
THANK YOU FOR YOUR KIND

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).